# Get count of a table based on info in a different table

Tags: php, sql, join

I have the following tables with the columns:

```
posts: title, user, date, state, city, blog
user: username, name, password, email, city, state, private
```

What I am trying to do is get the total number of records from posts where posts.state = user.state and user.private = 'public'. I tried the following which I know is wrong, but I think I'm close. Just trying to figure out the correct syntax.

```
 $sqlposts = "select p.*, u.state, u.private
              from posts p inner join user u on p.state = u.state
              where u.private = 'public'";
```

I have a total of 171 records saved, and this code only returns 52 records.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: This query seems to match exactly your requirement.  Can you show us sample data along with the expected output, and then point out where you think that output is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. "I have a total of 171 records saved?" How many "private"=Public? 52?
2. you used "inner join" which find only record both exist in 2 tables and will exclude those exist in one of 2 tables.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Right now, all users are set to public, so should see all 171 records, but when getting a count, only getting 52.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
$sqlposts = "select p.*, u.state, u.private
              from posts p left join user u on p.state = u.state
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I changed to a left join, got the same response.

Comment: Try this one. You need to remove u.private = 'public'"; from the where clause. Lete me know if you are getting right data. If you've any other problem, we're here for you.